Density of a subset of Schwartz space in the fractional Sobolev space
It is known that the Schwartz space $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ is dense in the fractional Sobolev space $H^s(\mathbb{R}^N)$, (where $0<s<1$), as $C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^N) \subset \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ and  $C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ is dense in $H^s(\mathbb{R}^N)$.
Recently, I saw a statement saying that the following subset of $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^N)$:
$$ \mathcal{A} := \left\{ f \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^N) : \mathcal{F}(f) \in C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^N \setminus \{ 0\}) \right\} $$
is dense in $H^s(\mathbb{R}^N)$, where $\mathcal{F}(f)$ is the Fourier transformation of $f$.
Observe that, $C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ does not contained in $\mathcal{A}$. Because of this observation, the density won't follow using the density of $C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^N)$.
I would be thankful if anyone could help me get this density result. Similar comments for $W^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ will be very helpful.

By $C_0^\infty$ you mean $C^\infty$ functions of compact support right? If you only mean functions $C^\infty$ functions that vanish at infinity, then you don't have the asserted inclusion $C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}^N) \subset \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^N)$.

Yes, I was referring to smooth functions with compact support. For clarity, I have revised the notation.

Just take FTs, and then you need to show that $C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb R^n\setminus 0)$ is dense in $L^2(\mathbb R^n, (1+|x|^{2s}), dx)$, which is obvious.

Thank you so much Sir, for the answer. Is this result true for the fractional Sobolev space W^{s,p}(R^N)? In this space, we generally do not have the representation of the norm in terms of Fourier transformation.
